# Conditional Probability with Ordered Stats

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-verification

I am very close to solving this, but this last part is killing me on how to solve it. I dont really know where to begin.

Scores run from 0 to 5 with density $f(x)=c(x^2-6x+10)$. An intermediate score is from 1 to 4.

I have found that $c=3/50$ and $E(X)=15/8$. $E(X)$ is the integral from $0\rightarrow5$ of $x*f(x)$.

The probability of an intermediate score is 153/200. The integral from $1\rightarrow4$ of f(x).

The question that I have is: If 100 students take the test what is the prob that at least 30 students will have an intermediate score?

I thought it could be conditional, but that does not make a whole lot of sense. We have not learned a lot of ordered statistics, but honestly I did not think of anything much other than that.

Comment: I don't know whether we are supposed to use a discrete model or a continuous one. Whichever we use, you can calculate the probability $p$ of an intermediate score. Then the number $Y$ of students with an intermediate score has binomial distribution, parameters $p$, $100$. The probability that $Y\ge 30$ can be computed exactly (software or a fancy calculator will do it) or else we can use the normal approximation.

Comment: I would assume it is continuous because of how the scores are set up. And we cannot use fancy stuff. But that is just using the binomial formula correct? the whole n choose k times the p^success times (1-p)^failed. where n is 100 and k is 30 and success is 30 and failed is 70?

Comment: The exact answer is $\sum_{k=30}^{100}\binom{100}{k}p^k (1-p)^{100-k}$. I have not checked whether your $p=153/200$ is correct.

Comment: why 50? I see why you get the sum part because it is at least. But why 50 and not 100?

Comment: Because I thought there were $50$ students! It would be more efficient, particularly if we are doing it by hand, to find instead the probability that the number is $\le 29$, and subtract from $1$.

Comment: Oh okay. I was like, where in the heck did that come from. You should put this as answer though. But I think I might just leave it in the notation and not solve by hand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know whether you are intended to use a discrete model, or the continuous model that you adopted. (In a number of places, grades from $0$ to $5$ are standard, with no intermediate grades.)

Let $p$ be the probability of an intermediate score. If your model and computation are correct, then $p=\frac{153}{200}$.

Let $Y$ be the number of students with an intermediate score. Then under the usual assumption of independence (students do not copy each other's answers), $Y$ has binomial distribution with parameters $p,100$. Then the exact probability is
$$\sum_{k=30}^{100}\binom{100}{k}p^k (1-p)^{100-k}.$$
It is more efficient to find first the probability of the complement (sum instead from $k=0$ to $29$) and then subtract this sum from $1$.

For a good approximation, we can use the normal approximation to the binomial.